# Doing a for-each record in a user defined table type in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

:)

I have this defined type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MyType
AS TABLE
(
name varchar(255),
value varchar(255)
);
```

Having this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure @docName varchar(255), @docPath varchar(255), @values AS [dbo].MyType Readonly
AS

declare @ID table (ID int)

INSERT INTO MyTable output inserted.fileID into @ID values (@docName,@docPath)

-- insert loop here

GO;
```

And the following "one to many" table

```
CREATE TABLE TableN (
fileID int PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(255),
value varchar(255)
)
```

How can I, where it is noted in the above code, make a loop in order to for each record in the `MyType` table, to insert it into TableN, together with the fileID from the `insert`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for a loop (you need to stop thinking programmatically in SQL and think in datasets). Just do an `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO TableN (FileID,[name],[value])
SELECT ID.ID,
       V.[Name],
       V.[value]
FROM @values v
     CROSS JOIN @ID ID;
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot!